# Are users confortable with the terms "Query" or "Dataset"?

Tags: terminology

I'm designing an application that let's users easily fetch data from a database and manipulate it in real time.
Think of writing SQL queries, but in a visual way, without having to learn all those jargon keywords. It is also in real time, much like applying filters, and sorting in an Excel file.

I'm thinking about using the term "Dataset" to refer to the object that allows performing these operations.

I was wondering if native English users, that are non-programmers, will be able to understand the term "Dataset".

I also thought about using the term "Query". But I'm not sure if any of the two are perceptible by non-programmers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, to a typical user, whether it's *data* or a *dataset* is mostly moot. As such, I'd simply say **data**.

*Query* isn't strictly technical, so I think that'd be a fine term to use--especially if your users are data savvy. That said, a perfectly suitable alternative may be **search**.

Comment: I agree, the term "dataset" is mostly used in the statistical field. Non-tech users will probably say "I'll save my data on the cloud", and not "I'll save my dataset on the cloud".

Answer (score 0):

Grid comes to mind as something more intuitive to non-programmers.

> Apply filters to your grid

I make this recommendation because it sounds like your query builder is not limited to a certain subset of data.

If you had mentioned that this is restricted to something like pulling additional data about a client then I would go with a more direct

> Apply filters to Client list

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reply? I didn't fully understand why you thought that using the term grid was a good ideia.
I know that there are some frameworks that have a datagrid feature.